# Microsoft.Net.Http.HttpClient throws FileNotFoundException at runtime

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

Anytime I instantiate a new HttpClient I run into a runtime exception. It compiles without issue and there's nothing that tells me I'm doing anything wrong. I've done some research online and see that this could a binding redirect issue, but wasn't really clear on how to address that or validate that this is still the issue (that recommendation was a few years old). Not being able to solve for this has brought my development to a stop :/

I've made a reproducible example for when this issue happens.

I create a new Xamarin.Forms project for iOS and Android.

[image]
[image]

I then create a new Unit Test project, using the nunit test framework.

[image]

My solution now looks like this:

[image]

I add the `Microsoft.Net.Http` NuGet package to both the Xamarin.Forms PCL project and my NUnit test project.

[image]

A create a new class called `WebRequest` that instantiates a new `HttpClient`. I then write my unit test that just instantiates a new `WebRequest` object.

[image]
[image]

My project structure at this point

[image]

I run the unit test and receive the following runtime exception.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
>
> at UnitTests.Test.TestCase () [0x00001] in /Users/johnathonsullinger/Source/Temp/TestHttpRequests/UnitTests/Test.cs:13
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
> at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.4.0/bockbuild-mono-4.4.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:295

Why is this a runtime issue but not a compile time issue? How do I resolve this? I just installed OS X brand new, and this is a fresh install of Xamarin Studio 6.0 (latest version from the alpha channel) and all of my packages are up to date.

Comment: You can flag `System.Net.Http` to be a local reference to get around that error, but you are trying to load a `Xamarin.Forms` based assembly into an NUnit .Net 4.5 instance and that will just result in an System.InvalidProgramException. I think you might be looking either to move your non-Forms-based logic into a stand-alone PCL-Library that can be loaded via a std. NUnit runner or add a Forms `UI Test App` to your solution.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. If I add a forms UI Test App, can I run actual unit tests, for the PCL shared code, or is that UI only testing? I can easily move the code into a PCL if not. Will a Xamarin.Forms PCL be able to consume a standard PCL that references the HttpClient class?

Comment: It would seem that moving the `System.net.Http.HttpClient` reference into a stand-alone PCL prevents the Xamarin.Forms project from consuming it :/ I'm disappointed that there's not a solution for writing actual unit tests for Xamarin.Forms yet. There are templates for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android template projects; none for Xamarin.Forms though

Comment: `none for Xamarin.Forms though`? Have you tried:  "New Project / Multiplatform / Tests / UI Test App" that is the Forms version, vs the "native" UI versions that you listed.

Comment: That template exists; when I read the Xamarin docs though, it sounded like those tests required the device, simulator or Xamarin Test Cloud to run. I'm looking for actual unit tests, that I can write without having to actually launch the app on a device.

Comment: For non-device specific code, you would need to move it into its own library (PCL or not) and then Yes you can NUnit test that using a non-mobile-device NUnit runner. Otherwise, for code that needs a mobile device as a context to run under, then running it local/remote with a emulator/physical device is the only way to go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111690/discussion-between-johnathon-sullinger-and-sushihangover).